# How to parse json data in in StickyHeader RecyclerView from Assets Folder

Tags: java, android, json, xml, kotlin

I want to show my JSON data in the sticky header recyclerview date-wise from the assets folder.The list  of Array is receive but not shown in recyclerview. I don't know where is my mistake. when I add toast it shows a complete JSON List.but not shown in recyclerview.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    var jobsArray = arrayListOf<String>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        loadJSONFromAsset()
    }
    private fun loadJSONFromAsset() {
        try {
            val json: String?
            val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open("test.json")
            json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
            var jsonArray = JSONArray(json)
            for (i in 0..jsonArray.length()) {
                var jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                jobsArray.add(jsonObject.getString("data"))
            }
            viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view).apply {
                viewAdapter = JobsAdapter(jobsArray)
                layoutManager = viewManager
                adapter = viewAdapter
            }
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                StickyHeaderItemDecoration(
                    recyclerView,
                    viewAdapter as JobsAdapter
                )
            )
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
class JobsAdapter(
    private var jobsArray: ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), StickyHeaderItemDecoration.StickyHeaderInterface  {

    override fun isHeader(itemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
    //return startTime[itemPosition].
    }
    override fun bindHeaderData(header: View, headerPosition: Int) {
        ((header as ConstraintLayout).getChildAt(0) as TextView).text =
            jobsArray[headerPosition]
    }
    override fun getHeaderLayout(headerPosition: Int): Int {
        return R.layout.row_header
    }
    override fun getHeaderPositionForItem(itemPosition: Int): Int {
        var headerPosition = 0
        var position = itemPosition
        do {
            if (this.isHeader(position)) {
                headerPosition = position
                break
            }
            position -= 1
        } while (position >= 0)
        return headerPosition
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            ViewHolderHeader(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.row_header, parent, false))
        } else {
            ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = jobsArray.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(holder is ViewHolder) {
            holder.nameView.text = jobsArray[position]
        } else if(holder is ViewHolderHeader) {
            holder.headerView.text = jobsArray[position]
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(true) {
            TYPE_HEADER
        } else {
            TYPE_ITEM
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val nameView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
    }
    class ViewHolderHeader(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val headerView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.headerView)
    }

}
```

**Json Data**(Im puting small chunk of json)

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 2158,
          "title": "job schedule 13",
          "description": "job schedule 13 description\n",
          "currency": "$",
          "type": "2",
          "days": "2",
          "start_time": "2021-09-13 13:20:57",
          "end_time": "2021-09-29 13:50:00",
          "total_workers": 30,
          "hourly_rate": 12,
          "status": "Pending",
          "user": {
            "id": 165,
            "name": "Asad Employer",
            "email": "",
            "mobile_number": "+92331435343",
            "status": "Active",
            "street_address": "ichra"
          },
]
```

Comment: Do you tried on debugging? Try it on `getItemCount()` in the recyclerview that you used and see whether the adapter receive any value or not

Comment: and also, why not parse these data as `data class` ?

Comment: when i debug this my app is crash at this line var jsonArray = JSONArray(json), i don't know how to pass data using data class for assets folder

Comment: what was the error message? and also it is highly recommend to parse your data into `data class` to ensure type-safety.

Comment: Error.. Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value (json response)

Comment: Can you try to parse ur data into data class first before passing it to adapter?

Comment: sir, I don't know how to parse to the data class can you please tell me. or please edit my code

Answer (score 0):

1. Create data class for the json data

```
data class AssetJSON(
    val data: List<Data>
)

data class Data (
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val currency: String,
    val type: String,
    val days: String,
    val start_time: String,
    val end_time: String,
    val total_workers: Long,
    val hourly_rate: Long,
    val status: String,
    val user: User
)

data class User (
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val email: String,
    val mobile_number: String,
    val status: String,
    val street_address: String
)
```

2. Install `Gson` into your project

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

3. Parse Json file into Json String as same as you does

```
private fun loadJSONFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String {
  return try {
        context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

4. Parse Json String into data class

```
val jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset(this, "test.json")
val data = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, AssetJSON::class.java)

// "data" now is your class
```

5. Pass this data into your adapter and see what error is thrown?

Comment: Sir, I implement this after the implementation Adapter showing many errors. Now how can I get the Position of the items?

Comment: Sir Your code is working fine but just tell me how I set the adapter accordingly?

Comment: Just pass these "data" into your adapter and use them into your adapter? There are many tutorial on how to pass value into recyclerview. And you must to know the basic concept of recyclerview